# How to display dynamic mysql vertical data to horizontal using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display dynamic mysql vertical data to horizontal in html table using PHP. And my table is like

```
mysql> select * from role_perm;

-------------------------------------------
| id  | userID  | roleID | permID | value | 
--------------- ---------------------------
| 1   |   2     |   1    |   1    | 1     |
|------------------------------------------
| 2   |   2     |   1    |   2    | 0     |
|------------------------------------------
| 3   |   2     |   1    |   3    | 0     |
|------------------------------------------
| 4   |   2     |   2    |   4    | 0     |
-------------------------------------------
| 5   |   2     |   2    |   1    | 1     |
|------------------------------------------
| 6   |   2     |   2    |   2    | 1     |
|------------------------------------------
| 7   |   2    |   2    |   3    | 0     |
|------------------------------------------
| 8   |   2     |   2    |   4    | 1     |
-------------------------------------------
| 9   |   5     |   1    |   1    | 1     |
|------------------------------------------
| 10  |   5     |   1    |   2    | 0     |
|------------------------------------------
| 11  |   5     |   1    |   3    | 0     |
|------------------------------------------
| 12  |   5     |   1    |   4    | 0     |
-------------------------------------------
```

and so on...

and i want to display in html table like

```
----------------------------
|  role | permissions      |
----------------------------
|   1   |   1 | 2 | 3 | 4  |
---------------------------- 
|   2   |   1 | 2 | 3 | 4  |
----------------------------
|   3   |   1 | 2 | 3 | 4  |
-----------------------------
|   4   |   1 | 2 | 3 | 4  |
----------------------------
```

could you pls help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the relation between the first and the second table? How is the data related?

Comment: Best to use a cross-tab query. Google 'php crosstab query' there are plenty of sites that will show you how to do this (I've lost the link to my favourite site).

Comment: what is role and what is permissions and what have you tried ?

Comment: You *can* use a crosstab query but I wouldn't call it 'best'. Issues of data display are *best* handled at the application level (assuming you have one)

Comment: and where does role 4 come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
roleID AS role,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT permID ORDER BY permID ASC SEPARATOR '|') AS permissions 
FROM role_perm 
GROUP BY roleID 
ORDER BY roleID
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply... but i want to show each permID in separate columns in a table.

Comment: So was redreggae's solution the one you were looking for? It seems like it wasn't. If not, please post the solution you found to help out others looking for help with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do this with a nifty MySQL query as well (which would supposedly be better for performance), but since I'm not that good at SQL, here's the PHP solution:

```
$arrRoles = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if (!isset($arrRoles[$row['roleID']])) {
       $arrRoles[$row['roleID']] = array();
   }
   $arrRoles[$row['roleID']][$row['permID']] = $row['value'];
}
var_dump($arrRoles);
```

Comment: @Strawberry: Obviously ... but I guess this retro-style is generally recognized and readable :-)

Comment: @Webberig: familiar, maybe, but we really don't need more code snippets with the deprecated functions lying around on the internet. Clean up your code to use the right library.

Comment: What do you call the right library ? Zend DB, Propel, Doctrine, mysqli, CI_DB ?